# Issue in reading data from excel in selenium c#

Tags: c#, excel, selenium-webdriver

This is my excel helper class

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EAAutoFramework.Helpers
{
public class ExcelHelpers
{
    private static List<Datacollection> _dataCol = new 
    List<Datacollection();

    // <summary>
    // Storing all the excel values in to the in-memory collections
    // </summary>
    // <param name="fileName"></param>
    public static void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
    {
        DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName);

        //Iterate through the rows and columns of the Table
        for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection()
                {
                    rowNumber = row,
                    colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                    colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                };
                //Add all the details for each row
                _dataCol.Add(dtTable);
            }
        }
    }

    private static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, 
        FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                var result = reader.AsDataSet(new 
                ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    ConfigureDataTable = (data) => new 
                    ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                    {
                        UseHeaderRow = true,
                    }
                });
                DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
                //Store it in DataTable
                DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];
                //return
                return resultTable;
            }
          }
        }

     public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
    {
        try
        {
            //Retriving Data using LINQ to reduce much of iterations
            string data = (from colData in _dataCol
                           where colData.colName == columnName && 
                           colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                           select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();


            return data.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
     }

   }

 public class Datacollection
  {
    public int rowNumber { get; set; }
    public string colName { get; set; }
    public string colValue { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

This is my main class in which i am calling excel helper function

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using EAAutoFramework.Base;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using EAEmployeeTest.PageObjects;
using EAAutoFramework.Helpers;
using EAAutoFramework.Config;
using EAEmployeeTest.PageObjects.PIM;

namespace EAEmployeeTest
{
[TestClass]

 //initialization has been done in hookInitialize
  public class UnitTest1: HookInitialize
  {

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + 
        "../TestDataAccess/TestData.xlsx";
        ExcelHelpers.PopulateInCollection(fileName);


        CurrentPage = GetInstance<LoginPage>();
        CurrentPage.AS<LoginPage>().EnterLoginCredentials(

  ExcelHelpers.ReadData(2,"Username"),ExcelHelpers.ReadData(2,"Password"));

        CurrentPage = CurrentPage.AS<LoginPage>().ClickLogin();
        LogHelpers.Info("Clicked on login");
        CurrentPage = CurrentPage.AS<HomePage>().ClickAdmin();

        CurrentPage.AS<AdminPage>().SearchAdminUser();

    }
```

But I am unable to read data from excel, it is throwing a null reference error[Message: Test method EAEmployeeTest.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: text cannot be null
Parameter name: text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNn6U.png)

Could any one help me on this on what i am missing over here. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting the exception, because you are returning null in `ReadData` on error. What is the exception in there?

Comment: public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
      {
         try
        {
             //Retriving Data using LINQ to reduce much of iterations
            string data = (from colData in _dataCol
                           where colData.colName == columnName && 
                           colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                           select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();


            return data.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
     }

   }

Comment: Why are you posting the code again? I've asked for the exception :)

Comment: I have also posted the exception @Ben

Comment: Ok. You misunderstood me. You have a method called `ReadData`. In this method you have a try...catch block. When there is an exception in this block, you are returning null. I think, in your case, this method returns null, because there is an exception. Please have a look at the method and make sure, that the return value is not null. If the return value is null, please post the exception from this try...catch block